# Golang Back-end and Angular Front-end with Prisma Generated Models import

Tags: angular, postgresql, go, prisma

I'm planning to have an application that will be having a `Golang` API Back-End with `Angular` Front-End and `PostgreSQL` Database. Few days ago I discovered `Prisma` and it rang a bell for me; if I create the DB schema first with `Prisma-Go-Client` then I'd be able to write Front-End and Back-End without creating any beans/models for DB manually and especially for the Front-End I'd directly start coding without any Database connection and API just using prisma generated imports that are `Typescript` models. So basically I could mock some temporary data with imported models and when Back-End would be ready consistent data types would flow and all I have to do it switch from mock data to bind it to the API request of the required data.

Now the question is; for `Golang` Back-End side its fine, I'll import `prisma-go-client` and generate the models and use them for any schema change and `CRUD` then return that data as a result etc. but what about Front-End? Should I create prisma TS client into existing `Angular` Front-End and generate models or this will result of a database reveal after the build of the code into the `dist`? Or if I create another project only for this purpose that will create `TS` prisma models and only get and import that models into the existing angular project will that work or will it still contain DB reveal?

Lastly, if `prima-go-client` creates models for `GoLang` and I parse the DB result into that model and return it as JSON to the Front-End, will `TS` generated prisma models be able to parse that response? or they will not be consistent since they are generated between two different languages and they will have difference (which I expect them to be same)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wouldn't work because the Prisma TS Client is not meant to be used on the frontend. It's a backend library, just like the Prisma Go Client.

You could use the Go Client within a type-safe GraphQL server like https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen and then use a type-safe GraphQL client on the frontend.

Just a note that the Go Client is no longer officially maintained: https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-go/issues/707. We'd recommend you use the TS client, if possible.

Comment: Lots of bad news here hehe :) But still lets assume that Go Client is officially supported and with a TS Client I generated stuff. Isn't it possible to copy only the beans/models from prisma without any back-end related just to be used in front-end type-safe data? I'm Honestly not planning to use any GraphQL, but not using prisma won't break my workflow too, I was just curious. And thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: @GüneySaramalı you could definitely do that. With the TS client you can import the types in your frontend with something like `import type { User } from "@prisma/client"`. Frontend models tend to diverge from backend models over time, so you'll want a way to separate them when the time comes.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as an answer if you don't have any more questions :-)

Comment: The Go client is now community-maintained by @steebchen (me): https://github.com/steebchen/prisma-client-go